# Encrypt the password in R

Tags: r, encryption, passwords, rodbc

Is there a way to encrypt the password in R.
I am connecting the database using OBDC connection string. So, when I pass the parameters, I will have to give the password as well as shown below. Can we hide this?

```
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver=/aaa/bbb/ccc.so;HOST=POIII.fda.gfd.vin.com;PORT=1001;UID=vipra;PWD=password",believeNRows = FALSE, rows_at_time = 1)
```

Expected output

```
conn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver=/aaa/bbb/ccc.so;HOST=POIII.fda.gfd.vin.com;PORT=1001;UID=vipra;PWD=*******",believeNRows = FALSE, rows_at_time = 1)
```

Comment: well you can use a function instead of a password. one example may be using `PWD=rstudioapi::askForPassword()`. that way you wouldnt store a variable but you would have to input your password all the time... another option would be `charToRaw()` or rather the opposite `rawToChar()` so your pw wouldn't be as easily decipherable.

Comment: Thanks. I thnk we can use ````charToRaw()````. Do you have sample for that?

Comment: not sure what you mean by sample. when i experimented with making passwords harder to read i just created raw data from my PW once, put it in a file and then let the script read the raw string from that file (which i hid deep in a folder structure) with `rawtochar()` from an import of that file (imported among many other files with lapply). tbh this was not good enough in the end but it was a great step up from having a variable with the password string inside my script :)

Comment: Got it.........

Comment: But again anybody can see the password in the file right? Can we put this password in a text file and lock that file?

Comment: no in the file is a raw data string

Comment: ok. But actually the purpose is not met right :)

Comment: RStudio has published a list of recommendations [here](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/managing-credentials/), the `keyring` package might be an attractive solution for your case, it uses AES for the pass and SHA256 for the access to that pass.

Comment: You could also have a look at [managing secrets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/secrets.html)